Wiring for VescUart with CAN-Bus
I'm building an RC car with four motors, each of which is controlled by a VESC. The main board is an arduino mega with four serial interfaces, but I need one to connect to another device, so I end up with three serial interfaces vs four VESCs.
So far, for testing, I used VescUart with a single VESC which worked fine except if I try using software serial, so "faking" a serial interface via software serial doesn't work.
Now the readme of the VescUart library promises communication with multiple VESCs using CAN bus. I have absolutely no idea about CAN but as far as I found out it requires special hardware. My question is, how to set up the arduino mega and the four VESCs so I can communicate with all four VESCs with just one UART connection.
My guess would be, one VESC is connected to the arduino over UART and works as the interface to the CAN bus and has canID = 0 which results in the VESC never treating the message as CAN relevant but just as directed to this VESC. If canID > 0 the interface VESC will just forward the message to the CAN bus and the appropriate VESC will read and if necessary reply. So all the VESCS are connected to the CAN bus like here. Any idea on how to do it without CAN is also welcome!
I'm using the VESC Firmware 5.03 on all the boards.
I just want to make sure it's correct before investing money in the CAN.
